# I have 2 problems with sqrt I solved the first one how can I solve it the second one like the first one? it is fairly diffucult then other

Tags: c#, math, sqrt

I know in this site homework or assigment stuff is not really welcome but I need help. I have an homework it contains 2 questions I already finished first one because it was easy. The second one isn't that much easy it is the same type of question but I think second one is harder then first one way too much. here is the first one I did.

first question:
[image: first question]

this is the answer for that question

```
Double a = 0;

            for(int i=1; i<100; i+=2)
            {

                a += (Math.Sqrt(i * (i + 1)));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Cevap= " + a);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

it was fairly easy and simple

second question *(NOTE: there is an error in the last term; `49*100` is incorrect, it should be `99*100`)*:
[image: second question]

they are a bit different but I think it's doable with the same codes but have to change a little bit.

now I don't want to an answer that answer the question but an answer to teach me how to do it. I know it's a bit arrogant to ask my homework here but I ask your help nonetheless.

Comment: 1. How many summands are there? This gives you the loop condition 2. How can the first term in each sqrt be derived from the loop variable? 3. How can the second term in each sqrt be derived from the loop variable?

Comment: The second question is quite strange. Based on the first terms, I would expect the formula to be sqrt((1+2i)*(50+i)) but it does not match the last term sqrt(49*100). Are you sure there is no error? Or am I wrong about the formula?

Comment: yes I am sorry the 49 needs to be 99 I am gonna edit it. @SnowGroomer

Comment: I am sorry everyone I can't seem to edit my post so I can't change the faulty second question it's indeed should be sqrt(99*100) and thanks to the Gaurav it has been solved. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series seems wrong as one side there are 25 terms and on the other side is 50 terms
**Assuming** that the last term of the series is sqrt(99*100)
This will solve the problem

```
Double a = 0;
int j = 50;
for(int i=1; i<=100; i+=2){   
       j++;         
       a += (Math.Sqrt(i * j));
     }
            
Console.WriteLine("Cevap= " + a);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Hope this solves your problem **but** if you try on with last term as sqrt(49*100) it will simply not be possible.

Comment: I am sorry everyone I can't seem to edit my post so I can't change the faulty second question it's indeed should be sqrt(99*100) and thansk to the Gaurav it has been solved. Thank you again!!

Comment: Old question, I know, but this seems like the perfect use of more than one variable being declared in the `for` loop header!: `for(int i=1, j=51; i<=99; i+=2, j++)`

Answer (score -1):

You can do `i+50` instead of `i+1` in the second term, and loop for `i<50` instead of `i<100`